# How to fix error in database: microsoft office access has detected corruption in this file

Tags: ms-access

I am in the process of developing an Access 2003 application, and almost done. While I was fixing some errors with controls on one of the reports, seems like the database corrupted. Now, I keep getting "microsoft office access has detected corruption in this file....etc". It instructs me to Compact & Repair, but when I get the same error message when I try that. If I open a blank database & try to import objects from the corrupted database, I cannot access/view the objects of the corrupted file from the blank database. Unfortunately, I dont have a backup of the file, I can try to restore to an earlier storage point (using System Restore), but will lose considerable work. Any ideas?

Comment: try to decompile the database, then compact and repair.  if that doesn't work you'll have to load one of your backups.  You do have backups... right....?? opps.. guess not.. that's commandment #10.  A system restore will not restore your database.  You unfortunately may be screwed...

Answer (score -2):

As far as my knowledge & experience is concerned, you can convert 2003 format to 2007, but not backwards, i.e. 2007 cannot be converted back to 2003. Please explain if I am missing something.

Also read: http://www.reddit.com/r/MSAccess/comments/2b4qlp/ms_access_mdb_ldb_database_corrupted/

Comment: OPs questions had nothing to do with converting the database?